# How to display a single instance of a Winform throughout the whole program?

Tags: .net, winforms, show, delphi-prism, single-instance

Accept my apology if my question and the description seems too simple or already been asked by others.

I may have asked a similar question before. However, I am still confused a little about winform. Say you have a Delphi prism .net program with **Mainform, Form1, Form2, Form3**. Plus, you want to be able to display a single instant of a Form1 from within Mainform, Form2 and Form3. How do you do that? I have to have a winform that needs to be displayed as needed throughout the whole program to show application errors within RichTextBox. This means SysErrorDlg winform can be called anytime from anywhere in my program to display program errors. For me to be able to do this is if only single instance of SysErrorDlg winform is accessible throughout my whole program.

follow the very simple code below. That's pretty much what I am trying to do.

```
=========================================
Mainform

using
Form1;
Form2;
Form3;   

Mainform1 = class(System.Windows.Form)
private
method ShowBtn_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs)
public
constructor;
F1:Form1;
end;

constructor MainForm1;
begin
   F1 := new Form1;
end;

method Mainform1.ShowBtn_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
   F1.Show; // or ShowDialog;
end;

=====================================================
Form1

Form1 = class(System.Windows.Form)
private
public
constructor;
end;

constructor Form1;
begin

end;

=====================================================
Form2

using
Mainform;

Form2 = class(System.Windows.Form)
private
method ShowBtn_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs)
public
constructor;
end;

constructor Form2;
begin

end;

method Form2.ShowBtn_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
   MainForm1.F1.Show; // or ShowDialog;
end;

====================================================
Form3

Using
MainForm;

Form3 = class(System.Windows.Form)
private
method ShowBtn_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs)
public
constructor;
end;

constructor Form3;
begin

end;

method Form3.ShowBtn_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
   MainForm1.F1.Show; // or ShowDialog;
end;

============================================
```

Is it even possible to do that? My compiler won't let me declare a global winform variable but complains that it needs to be identified to be a public. Even if there is an option to enable this feature, I don't want to for I like the idea of keeping variables private or local to classes.

**How do you pass the instance of the form1 to form2 or form3 if an instance of form1 is already declared and instantiated within Mainform? I understand how show and showdialog work. What line of code would you use to access Form1 instance from Form2 if the Form1 instance is within MainForm?**

You could provide a little code along with your explanation.

Comment: You need to prevent the form from being closed by the user until your app terminates.  That requires overriding OnFormClosing() so you can set e.Cancel = true.  Pay attention to e.CloseReason.  This kind of user interface is unusual.

Comment: @Hans I am already aware of that and have implemented my code to do just that when a winform is being closed within formclosing event. I don't think you understand my question. I should have worded my question this way, "How to make winform global?"

Comment: Assign it to a static variable, if you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the **singleton-pattern** for this.
For example, in c# I could define **Form1** like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Form1 _theform;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the one and only instance of Form1.
    /// </summary>
    static public Form1 TheForm
    {
        get
        {
            if ( null == _theform )
            {
                _theform = new Form1();
            }

            return _theform;
        }
    }

    protected Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then, anywhere in my application I can get the same instance of Form1 by doing this:

```
Form1.TheForm.Show();
```

Comment: Yep. When your coworkers criticise you for using a global, tell them it's singleton.

Comment: @FastAl So, by your logic, using MATH.ROUND method throughout your project files makes it a singleton. Pretty much that's what I am trying to do. All I want is to display a simple winform with 2 controls on it and be accessible throughout my program. Now, if one can't do that with Delphi Prism for .NET, then I can't imagine anyone writing a complex and sophisticated process or automation system for the real world. In fact, I am trying to write and develope a pretty big automation system for .NET.

Comment: @Ahazzah, thank you for your suggestion. I created a static winform and it works great. I guess, static is only way to go in this situation. Whether it's singleton or not, this question stands as a proof that sometimes you just can't do without global or static variables.

Answer (score 1):

You, can use the Help of `ShowDialog()` for this purpose. For Example, if F1 is the Object of Form1 then by calling form1 with `F1.ShowDialog()` for first time will open the Form1 and for the second time it will not allow to call until the first instance window is gets closed. But where as `F1.Show()` will opens multiple windows of Form1 for every call.

Comment: I understand that very well. That's not really my problem. Maybe I should add more details with pseudo code in my description. I will do that in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Display form1 using `Form1.show()` (instead of `Form1.showdialog()`).
Then use Hide instead of Close to hide the form: `Me.Hide()` . This leaves an instance of the form running, and it can be accessed by other forms in the application.

Then, for example, if Mainform puts text in a richtextbox of Form1, it will be there when Form2 and Form3 show Form1.

Comment: you are 100% correct in that calling show leaves an instance of the winform running to be able access it later if you hide it when closing. Again, that's not my real issue here. How do you get access to the first instance of Form1 from Form2 or Form3 based on the simple code I provided in my description.

Comment: If you use .hide instead of .close, the first instance will be accessed when referred to in Form2 and Form 3. For example, from Mainform, Show Form1 and put some text in a text box. Then .hide form1. Then load form2 and show form1 from form2. The text will still be there, because it is the same instance.

Comment: xpda, I agree with you. The thing is compiler won't let me get access to the form itself. I keep getting "instance of the form is needed" error. How do you pass the instance of the form1 to form2 or form3 if an instance of form1 is already declared and instantiated within Mainform? Do you see what I am getting at? I understand how show and showdialog work. What line of code would you use to access Form1 instance from Form2 if the Form1 instance is within MainForm?

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example that works, but in VB. Maybe you can eliminate some possibilities that way. I remember one oddity that requires a class to be public before accessing a public instance. If they're not already, you might try declaring your form classes public. (That's just a guess, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping a form's instance active is probably not the best approach. I'd suggest to separate the logging from the display of the log.

The idea would be to use the technologies available in .NET for logging and/or tracing (i.e. static Trace class) and simply append a specific listener that will keep track of all logged entries throughout the application, as well as provide read-access to this log.

Then you can show your Log-window whenever required. This log window simply accesses the listener and uses databinding to display the listeners content in the text field.

By using databinding you can also make sure that, as soon as new entries are written in the log, the display automatically updates.

This way you can close and re-instanciate the form whenever required without 'hacking' around the restrictions you currently encounter.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to have small winform with close button and RichTextBox which will display errors of my application NOT the window's system error. So, what it will do is if a user try to do access undefined element or data in the program, it will load the error on to the RichTextBox and show the winform. For my program to be able to do that, it needs to have one instance of this winform every time it goes to do that. In Delphi win32 app, you just created a TForm and listed the unit file in the uses clause anywhere you needed to have access to its TForm. That's what I want

Comment: I could work around this issue if delphi prism won't let me do it by writing all the errors into a file. Everytime my app needs to show the errors, it will create a new instance of the winform and load the error into RichTextBox from the file and display. This workaround is not really a great solution for it requires too many steps to do a simple task. But I am sure it will work.